# Converting to bangla language in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I save bangla language data into database.But when want I retrieve and print it,

```
NSLog(@"Database Dictionary is %@",valueFromDBDictionary);
```

**Output is**

Database Dictionary is

```
{
 "name_bn" = "\U2021\U00b6\U00e1\U2021\U00b6\U2260\U2021\U00df\U00e1\U2021\U00b6\U00ae\U2021\U00df\U00e7\U2021\U00b6\U00fc";
}
```

and when print this way,

```
NSLog(@"Bangla value is %@",[valueFromDBDictionary objectForKey:@"name_bn"]);
```

**Output is**

Bangla value is `‡¶™‡ßÇ‡¶ú‡¶æ.`

But in database it save as real Bangla alphabet like that `"পূজা"` . Now, question is how I get the real Bangla alphabet.

Comment: Try setting this text in a label with font name "Bangla Sangam MN".

Comment: try to print in UILabel... you will see it correctly... NSLog is not coming bcz of not setting to UTF-8

Comment: I am try to print in UILabel with font name "Bangla Sangam MN". But it does not working.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't checked it but could you try and see(assuming value is const char):

```
NSLog(@"Bangla value is %@",[NSString stringWithUTF8String:[valueFromDBDictionary objectForKey:@"name_bn"]]);
```